# How to install and use GNU unifont in cygwin on Windows7?

Tags: unicode, windows-7, fonts, cygwin, gnu

I'm using GNU unifont on FreeBSD and would like to have the same font available under Windows7 in a cygwin terminal. My attempts to install GNU unifont for general use (so it would be available in font selection) in Windows7 were futile, as I'm a newcomer to the Seattle family of operating systems.

I have the unifont available in many formats (ttf.gz, zip, bdf.gz, pcf.gz), as offered on [GNU Unifont Glyphs](http://unifoundry.com/unifont.html). Can a cygwin terminal be made to use any of these?

Comment: Erm, nice avatar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of teaching a Windows `cmd.exe` window to use GNU unifont, I decided to install X11 for Cygwin, then configure X11 to use the desired font. That way I have all the goodies of xterm right at my fingertips. Here's how to do it.

1. If you haven't already, install the X11 that comes with Cygwin. See Cygwin/X User's Guide http://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/cygwin-x-ug.html for details. When selecting additional X11 utilities, be sure to add `mkfontdir` and `xset` from category X11.
2. Decide for a directory to place the GNU unifont. I chose `~/X11/font` for the following.
3. `cp unifont.pcf.gz ~/X11/font/unifont.pcf.gz`
4. `mkfontdir ~/X11/font`
5. If not already running, start an X server, e.g. with `startxwin`
6. `export DISPLAY=:0`
7. `xset +fp ~/X11/font`
8. `xterm -fn '-gnu-unifont-medium-r-normal--16-160-75-75-c-80-iso10646-1'`

Voilà!

You probably want to place the commands starting with step 6 in `~/.startxwinrc` so they get read and executed automatically by `startxwin`.

Comment: You can also use the Cygwin within Console2, where you can change fonts easily.http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/